# Dynamically Loading AS2 file in AS3 - how to tell if the file is AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I have a Flash program that loads AS2 and AS3 SWF files dynamically with the same function.  I'm trying to convert all the AS2 files to AS3, but I don't have the FLA for some, so they will need to remain AS2.

What I need to do is if the file getting loaded is AS3, I need to run an additional set of code to setup some interactive features.  If it's AS2, I just want to load it.

What would the code be for checking to see if a dynamically loaded SWF file is AS2?

Thanks

---

Update.  It looks like the  actionScriptVersion is what I'm looking for, but it's not working the way I expected.  I have in my code:

```
trace(loader.loaderInfo.actionScriptVersion);
```

But when I try and load a file I know is AS2, I get 3 instead of 2.  Am I using this code incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the actionscriptVersion property of the loaded content's loaderInfo property:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#actionScriptVersion

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm trying to do, but it's not working correctly for some reason.

Comment: You want loader.content.loaderInfo.actionScriptVersion or contentLoaderInfo.actionScriptVersion. The loader is in the AS3 swf, so it would be as3!